# How can I check a specific word by specifying that word as a input for grep

Tags: bash

I want to locate the error code (like 500,200,404) from the apache log file.  the error code must be taken as input given by me, ( when I run the script it must prompt like

> " please enter the error code here (404,500,200): ..... "

when I enter the error code, it must sort and show the word count of that particular error happened in that apache log. and ask me to specify a name to save the file.

I am new to script, what I tried is below.

```
read -p "Enter the error code : " CODE

 #echo 'Your Error code is,HTTP/1.1"' $CODE

 cat test.txt | grep 'HTTP/1.1" $CODE' | wc -l
```

'HTTP/1.1" 500' or 'HTTP/1.1" 200' is the actual word I want to search, because if I grep 500 only,  there will be more output. (like there is any other 500 is there it also pop up, I need only the 'HTTP/1.1" "error code" ' (error code which I mention as input while prompting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: `cat test.txt | grep "HTTP/1.1 $CODE" | wc -l`
You must use double quotes and make sure you have the correct number of spaces between the HTTP/1.1 and the 500.

Comment: @sreejuks : Like AAber said, but if you don't know the number of spaces, respectively if this can vary, use a suitable regexp instead, for instance `... grep -E "HTTP/1.1 +$CODE"`

Comment: Or `grep "HTTP[/]1[.]1.*$CODE$"`

Comment: unfortunately double quotes not work here i think. There is also a double quote in the error code. this is the actual error code in the log HTTP/1.1" 500  <-

[17/Aug/2019:23:48:00 +0500] "POST /path/path/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0000 "-" "-"
2019-08-17T23:48:00+05:00 app-server apache: 192.168.0.1 - -

this  is the entire log, from this i want to sort the 500 error only (the above log is edited due to security reasons)
i can grep this using >--> grep 'HTTP/1.1" 500' | wc -l  in terminal, but i cannot do this in script with a input specified unless i have to mention the error in the script itself.